# Calling command line arguments in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program in Python 3 that will take data from a csv file, make adjustments to it and write the new data to a csv file that will be named by the user.

I'm just trying to understand the command line part.
I want it to execute properly in this format.

```
$ program.py input.csv output.csv
```

I plan to also make it check that there are 3 total arguments.

My question is where do this filename inputs on the command line go?
Are they saved to a default variable? How can I call these filenames within my python program?

Answer (score 7):

Command line options are stored in sys.argv. You may want to check this:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=argv#sys.argv

Beside, if you need more complex command-line argument parsing and deciding your program logic based on that, you should try [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse)

Comment: For calling these filenames, you already have sys.popen, os.system, subprocess modules.