# How can I call Python script from URL and get parameters

Tags: python, url, server

I call my script with http://domain/script.py
How can I call the script with a parameter and get the parameter in the python script when I call it like http://domain/script.py?parmameter=value
I can't find a solution or even find out if this is possible or not.
Would be very happy fo a solution.
Thanks to all.

---

**edit**:
I run it now from php:
http://domain/script.php?parmameter=value

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['parmameter'])){
    $myval = $_GET['parmameter'];
    $command = escapeshellcmd("python script.py $myval" );
    ...
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) if you do not care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us more about your setup and what is working. What is serving your Python script? Are you using a Web server like nginx or Apache?
You can not normally run a Python script via a Web browser without some kind of interface - otherwise you would just get the source of the Python file served as text.
If you were using Flask or Django as a Web framework, then these have built-in ways to access the query strings.

EDIT: since you're calling it as a shell script, you want to get the *command line arguments*.

Have a look at this answer: [Calling command line arguments in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596694/calling-command-line-arguments-in-python-3)

You can get the value of your `$myval` variable with: `import sys` then  `sys.argv[1]` (but best to check that it exists before trying to access it, or use exception handling).

Comment: I am not sure, this is a webhosting with python support (no more infos). I have also SSH access but it is not possible to run python from terminal, only from url.

Comment: Right, so you are running it via a shell command essentially, and you want to get the command line arguments.

Comment: Were you happy with this answer, @oxidworks? Did it help solve your problem?

Comment: no, because I can't run python from command line, only from URL. So I need to use PHP to get args.